# Uploading image in struts2

Tags: struts2, multipartform-data

I have problem when upload image in Struts2.

I am trying to upload an image from jsp page to action class in struts2

My code is successfully run but executes up to System.out.println("2") and the image is not copied to the specified location.

Please help me to solve this problem

My Action class is below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class upload extends ActionSupport  {

public String execute()throws Exception
{
    try{

    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

    System.out.println("1");
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

    System.out.println("2");
    for (FileItem item : items)
    {
        System.out.println("3");
            if (!item.isFormField()){
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            System.out.println(fieldname);

            System.out.println("4");
            File file = new File("F:/www/test/Rohit/workspace_Rohit/uploadWithStruts2/WebContent/uploadimage","hi.jpg");        
            item.write(file);
         }
    }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

My jsp page is:

```
<form action="test.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="image">
                <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// For upload Image in Struts2

// Jsp Page is: 

<s:form method="post" action="test.action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<s:file name="imageFile" label="User Image" />
<s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>


//Struts.xml

<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<action name="test" class="Test">
        <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>


//Test.java

import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
public class test extends ActionSupport{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private File imageFile;

public File getImageFile() {
    return imageFile;
}

public void setImageFile(File imageFile) {
    this.imageFile = imageFile;
}

public String execute()throws Exception
{
    try{

        //code for image random name
        // start from here to 

         DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
         Date date = new Date();
         String dt = format.format(date);

         String name = "";
         StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(dt);
         while (str.hasMoreElements())
         {
             String nm=(String) str.nextElement();
             name+=nm;
         }

         String name1="";
         StringTokenizer strg = new StringTokenizer(name,"/");
                 while (strg.hasMoreElements())
                 {
                     String nam=(String) strg.nextElement();
                     name1+=nam;
                 }

         String imgname="";   
         StringTokenizer strge = new StringTokenizer(name1,":");
                 while (strge.hasMoreElements())
                 {
                     String na=(String) strge.nextElement();
                     imgname+=na;   
                 }


    //code for copy image to specific path

    String sourceFilePath=imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    //System.out.println(sourceFilePath);
    File sourceFile=new File(sourceFilePath);   
    File destnationFile=new File("E:/Jaydip_Baldha/workspace_new/Struts2Upload/WebContent/upload_image/"+imgname+".jpg");
    FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destnationFile);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS; 
}
```

}